# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation not working - UIImageView - iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

For a bit of fun and practise, I am trying to make a simple analogue clock iOS app. Anyway, I have an issue with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation, it just doesn't work. To start of with, I am rotating the second hand. But it just keeps the hand in the same place.

So how am I trying to do it?

Well in a circle there are 360 degrees, so in every second there is (60/360) 0.16666666666 degrees.

I then convert this to radians and then times it by the current second count. But it doesn't really work :(

Here is my code:

```
-(void)update_the_timer {

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
time_label.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

NSString *test = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *time = [dateFormatter dateFromString:test];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate: time];

NSInteger seconds = [components second];


// Convert degrees to radians: x * M_PI/180.0
float number = ((0.16666666666 * (M_PI/180.0)) * seconds);
NSLog(@"%f", number);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    second_handle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(number);
}];
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks for your time, Dan :)

Comment: FYI - unrelated to your issue but you should not recreate your date formatters over and over. Create them once and save them in instance variables so you can reuse them over and over. They are expensive to create. Also, don't call `[NSDate date]` twice. Call it once and store it in a variable. It's more efficient and both uses work on the same date each time.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the advice. I will certainly do that. Thanks once again.

Comment: This has some examples: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, very useful for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to turn the seconds to degrees calculation on its head before converting to radians, in every second there's 6 degrees:

```
float number = (M_PI/180.0) * seconds * 6;
```